# How can I extract the value of an app.inventory.id command-line argument?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a line with:

```
-Dapp.id=XXX -Dapp.name=YYY -Dapp.inventory.id=KKK -Dapp.inventory1.id=UNDEFINED -app.id=MMM
```

in an *inventory.txt* file. If I use the grep statement below, I get the entire line instead of only `KKK`:

```
grep -F app.inventory.id= /cme/apps/install/*/inventory/*.txt
```

I also tried flags like `-Fx` and `-w`, but nothing works. How can I get the just `KKK` using grep?

Comment: I know this is a crappy thing to say, but use `sed` or `awk` instead. It will let you control which part gets printed. `grep` will too with the `-o`, but it will include the `-D...` part too.

Comment: you can use the option : grep -o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `sed` is a bit nicer here:

```
sed -n 's/.*-Dapp.inventory.id=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/gp' /cme/apps/install/*/inventory/*.txt
```

If you want the filename you can do something like

```
for filename in /cme/apps/install/*/inventory/*.txt; do 
    sed -n -e 's/.*-Dapp.inventory.id=\([^ ]*\).*/'$filename': \1/gp' $filename; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - worked great

Comment: i am getting the value of the sed, is it possible to get the filename that is sed is operated on? I have multiple .txt files in that path. help me please

Comment: I've added a way to get the filenames as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with just grep, you can use a grep with the PCRE library built in. For example:

```
$ pcregrep -o 'app.inventory.id=\K[^[:space:]]+' /tmp/corpus
KKK
```

Alternatively, if you don't have PCRE available you can use grep with extended regular expressions, and then use cut to get the correct field by using `=` as a field delimiter. For example:

```
$ grep -Eo 'app.inventory.id=\K[^[:space:]]+' /tmp/corpus | cut -d= -f2
KKK
```

Answer (score 0):

if all the files have same types of output wich means :

```
-Dapp.id=VALUE -Dapp.name=VALUE -Dapp.inventory.id=VALUE -Dapp.inventory1.id=VALUE [...]
```

You can then use awk like this :

```
grep -F app.inventory.id= /cme/apps/install/*/inventory/*.txt | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | awk -F '=' '{print $2}
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -Eo "\s-Dapp.inventory.id=[A-Z]+\s" inventory.txt | cut -d '=' -f2`

**grep**

- -E use extended regex,
- -o output only the match
- `[A-Z]+\s` matches Uppercase-Letters to the next whitespace

To see the match:
`grep --color -Eo "\s-Dapp.inventory.id=[A-Z]+\s" inventory.txt`

**cut**

- -d --delimiter=DELIM delimiter of fields,
- -f --fields=LIST output only the selected fields

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo -Dapp.id=XXX -Dapp.name=YYY -Dapp.inventory.id=KKK -Dapp.inventory1.id=UNDEFINED -app.id=MMM | 
  awk -v RS=' +' '/app.inventory.id/{split($0,a,"=");print a[2]}'

KKK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[= ]' '{print $6}' file
KKK
```